# Relabeling all indices on pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have an `xslx` file which I've set its' `ID` column to be my index on pandas.

Index starts at `3200` up to `3509`. I'm requested to relabel all of my index values meaning, `ID` column value so that each index has a prefix named `sub_`. For example, for `index 3200`, I'm requested to change it to `sub_3200` and so on and so forth.

I've tried using `reindex`, after creating a dictionary in which all of the values are the modified names `('sub_3200', ...)`. I tried reindexing using `dictionary.values()`, which does change the labels of the indices, however all of the other values in the data frame now appear as `NaN`, even though there were values before hand.

How can I relabel my index without harming the rest of the data frame?

Answer (score 2):

#### Hack

```
df.T.add_prefix('sub_').T
```

---

#### Less Hack

```
df.set_index('sub_' + df.index.astype(str))
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you tell me what's the logic behind 'reindexing' not working?

Comment: Reindexing is aligning an existing index with a new index.  It doesn't change the names of the index values.

Comment: This df.set_index('sub_' + df.index.astype(str)) works for me. Thanks :)